# SFML - windows glitch

Tags: c++, sfml

I want my window to start maximized and i found a line of code using windows.h to automatically maximize the window, but every couple of times i start the window it will do this visual glitch:
[image]

idk why, is there any fix or an alternative way of maximizing the window?

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1017), "Testing"); ShowWindow(window.getSystemHandle(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help you just from a screenshot. Also, the "glitch" seems to be indicate that portions (or all) of the window are not updated.

Comment: oh shoot my bad, it was
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1017), "Testing");
ShowWindow(window.getSystemHandle(), SW_MAXIMIZE);